# How share a config file in git?

Tags: git, git-config

I have editor settings that I want to spread in all repositories. If the user defines its own settings, it should erase the repository choices of course.

I want to do that because I have a class and every student clone the repo. Usually they forget to set the core.editor setting and ends up messing around with vi, usually crashing the repo just like if they have cursed magical power.

As it worked for my HOME dir, I tried to use a .gitconfig in my repo dir, like I would set a .gitignore, but it doesn't seem to work.

EDIT :

- `--global` DOES let the user set its preference to override the repo, but it DOES'T allow him to fetch the repos config while cloning it.
- .git/config is not shared among cloned repo

Comment: It seems like the proper solution is to educate your students on the use of EDITOR, VISUAL, and GIT_EDITOR.  That's good general knowledge to have in any case.

Comment: Education is easy if you have all the time you want to spend with every student individually. This is not the case. I'd rather find an automatic solution and spend time on more important things.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Distribute your repo using rsync or tar/untar, rather than using "git clone", which as you have seen, does not copy repo-special files.

Answer (score 2):

I do this by moving the config file up to the working dir to get it versioned.

Then you could ask the other person to make a link to the config:

```
$ rm .git/config
$ cd .git
$ ln -s ../config config
```

You could then write this in a script or in one line to let them copy and paste.

Comment: But what if they also have custom settings in their config file? This would wipe out these settings.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a shell script in the repo that sets these values through `git config`. That would allow the students to see how they do it themselves, and it gives them a way to undo their local settings.

Unfortunately, this wouldn't be automatic.

Example:

```
#! /bin/sh
git config core.editor "ed"
```

Comment: Definitly a bad idea. A script in wich language ? You better have a language that all students understand well. And you'll have to spend time on this, which is something you always lack, as stated in my previous comments.

Comment: I meant a sh script that has the git commands to setup the defaults. Unless your students aren't using git on the command line?

Comment: @e-satis why should the students need to understand the language of the script? About time, you do have to spend some time on this irrelevant of how you do it.

Comment: You don't just ask your student to run a custom script and don't tell them what it does. In real life, they won't have the script. They need to understand it. At least with a defaut config file, they would concentrate on understanding the git configuration à home.

Comment: @e-satis: True. You want your students to understand how things work so they can apply their understanding later. But if the git repo is automatically configured, how would they know how to replicate that setup on their own? (If they start setting up their own repos, then they likely won't know why their new repos are different from their class repo.)

Comment: I can give that as homework, giving them the file. I don't wish to give them additional stuff to study such as a script wich has nothing to do with learning git.

Answer (score -4):

Global settings can be set via: `git config --global`

Maybe you should first let the students clone the configuration file (from its own repository) to their home directories.

Comment: it does not allow me to share any git configuration.