# How do I make git insert version information into a file?

Tags: git, githooks, git-config, git-filter

In my git repository, I would like to insert the “current version” into a file automatically.  To this end, I made a filter

```
[filter "version"]
    clean = perl -pe 's[\\$version:.*\\$][\\$version:\\$]'
    smudge = "perl -pe 'chomp($v=qx(git describe)); s[\\$version:.*\\$][\\$version:$v\\$]'"
```

This works like a charm for me, but how do I propagate this to other people who might clone my repository?

According to this question ([How share a config file in git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246465/how-share-a-config-file-in-git)), it is not possible to do this by sharing the filter (which is part of the config file) directly.  *What would be the most robust way to insert a version number using git?*

Obviously, I could have `make` do the job, but what if you don't call `make`?  (In my case, `make` is called, but the file in question is a script which would otherwise not be touched by `make`.)

Side questions:

- I put “current version” in quotes above because that term is not so easy to define in this context; `git describe` works for me so far, but I am open for suggestions.
- The project is hosted on GitHub.  If a user downloads the code through a release, it would be nice to insert the version automatically there, as well.  I guess this does not work with my current approach.

Comment: I can't speak for *most* robust, but one typical way to get people to set up a hook and filter is to provide them a `./setup.sh` or `./config` or whatever that, as part of the sequence of setting them up so that the software will build at all, also checks for the need to set up a hook and filter.